# How do you pass data between divs and into {% if %} statements

Tags: python, html, django

I have multiple  tags that target another div with the id="pop"

```
{% for user in pull %}
    <a href="#pop">Link: {{user.user_name}} {{ user.user_id }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

which looks like this

```
Link: tom 2
Link: ann 8
Link: mike 3
```

When i click on each link the div with the id="pop" pops up.

inside the pop div tag i have the following code

```
<div id="pop">
    {% for user in pull %}
            {% if user.user_id == (??? user.user_id Link: tom 2 ???) %}
                {{ user.question }}<br>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My question is is there any way to pass the user.user_id which equated to 2 from the link to if statement between the brackets?

Comment: Surely you would need to do that in your javascript?

Comment: it looks like the architecture of your app needs more thought. you are mixing two separate concepts. the `{% %}` patterns are unfolded on the server side, but the click happens on the client.

Comment: You understand that the python code `{% %}` runs on the server side and javascript runs on the client side (user browser) right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can do this by 2 ways. 
1)One is using jquery 
2)second is do a popup code inside same forloop with unique div id as below

```
{% for user in pull %}
    <a href="#pop{{user.user_id}}">Link: {{user.user_name}} {{ user.user_id }}</a>

    <div id="pop{{user.user_id}}">
                {{ user.question }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is easy way then jquery, just issue is redundant code for popup.

If you want jquery code also, just comment here.

Comment: this worked thank you, but i want to target each individual new pop from the css, pop1, pop2, pop1000, and make it transition from 0 opactity to 1 opacity, i might make a new question for it now, but awesome thank you!